# regex - illegal repetition?

Tags: java, regex

Working with Regex in Java. I keep trying to get this to work, but it throws the damn error each and every time. I'm convinced it has to do with the curly braces.

```
String openbrace = Pattern.quote("{");
String closebrace = Pattern.quote("}");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(openbrace+"[ ]?\"(.*?)\"[ ]?,[ ]?\"(.*?)\"[ ]?"+closebrace);
```

+

```
{ "Working", "Working" },
```

=

```
Illegal Repetition
```

EDIT: I am using NetBeans 7.0 with JDK 1.7

Comment: Does just `Pattern.compile("[ ]?\"(.*?)\"[ ]?,[ ]?\"(.*?)\"[ ]?")` compile?

Comment: Yep. As I said - it's gotta be those braces.

Comment: What about `Pattern.compile("\\{[ ]?\"(.*?)\"[ ]?,[ ]?\"(.*?)\"[ ]?\\}")`? Check the content of those strings. Should just be `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: Why do you need to wrap spaces in square brackets?

Comment: Your pattern gives the Illegal Repetition error. The string "closebrace" outputs to the console as "\Q}\E".

Comment: @bolt I don't. But that's not the problem. Thanks for pointing it out anyways :)

Comment: Using Netbeans 6.9.1 here. Not getting any error.

Comment: 7.0 - Did you compile and run?

Comment: Weird.  In QuickRex (Eclipse plugin for playing with regexes) "\Q{\E[ ]?"(.*?)"[ ]?,[ ]?"(.*?)"[ ]?\Q}\E" - the same thing - works fine.

Comment: Very strange... for me it works (eclipse 3.7.0, java 1.6.0_24) and matches what it should.

Comment: Does anybody have NetBeans 7.0 with JDK 1.7? If so, please test this!

Comment: I've updated to NetBeans 7.0, updated the JDK (it says "1.6.0_26", not "1.7"), no error.

Comment: Adding one other cause to this question/answer.  I hit this error when my code was accidentally feeding in the source string to match against as the regex pattern instead.  The source was from log files so it also had curly braces in it.  Obviously a bone-head maneuver.

Answer (score 5):

How about `"\\{\\s*\"(.*?)\"\\s*,\\s*\"(.*?)\"\\s*\\}"` ?

Have just compiled and run the following program. Runs correctly:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\s*\"(.*?)\"\\s*,\\s*\"(.*?)\"\\s*\\}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("{ \"working\", \"working\"}");

        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.start(1) + " - " + m.end(1));
            System.out.println(m.start(2) + " - " + m.end(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Illegal Escape Character" says NetBeans IDE

Comment: Is it without openbrace and closebrace?